# How to count background notification messages, using Angular 7 & FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently implementing a counter of notifications, based on received push notifications by firebase-messaging-sw.js & messaging.service.ts.
I have counted notifications in messaging.service.ts (foreground notifications) and emit value of this notifications to my main component using BehaviourSubject, where I'm able to display amount of these new notifications (received push notifications when we are in application), but I'm now struggling how to emit (amoutOfNotifications) value of background notifications counted in firebase-messaging-sw.js (JS file) to my main component (TypeScript file).

> firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
    messagingSenderId: 'MY-SENDER-ID'
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
let amountOfNotifications = 0;

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    if (payload.data.notification_type === 'message_001') {
        amountOfNotifications = amountOfNotifications + 1;
        console.log('amount of background notifications', amountOfNotifications);
        // how to emit amoutOfNotifications to another typescript component???
    }
    // here you can override some options describing what's in the message;
    // however, the actual content will come from the Webtask
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: 'New activity'
    };
    return self.registration.showNotification('Example App', notificationOptions);
});
```